# what is the equivalent of ToString("00.00000") in C++?

Tags: c++

I tried the following to get .ToString("00.00000") but failed

```
char buf[500];
memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));
sprintf_s(buf, "%02.7f",abc);
std::string abc_str = buf;
```

i realised that the %02 doesnt have any effects, example when i get a 7.0, the result is 7.0000000 rather than the desired 07.0000000, anything wrong here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char buf[500];
    printf("%010.7f\n", 7.0);
}
```

#### Output:

```
07.0000000
```

#### Comments

Note that 10 is the minimum width of the entire field, not just the left hand side of the decimal.

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent in C++ would be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::setw(10) << std::setfill('0') 
              << std::fixed    << std::setprecision(7) << 7.0;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
07.0000000
```

If you need to actually store it into a `std::string`, then:

```
#include <sstream>

std::ostringstream oss;
// ...
std::string s = oss.str();
```